# How to select all data from a table into a single string output in sql

Tags: sql

Just wandering, is there any way that I can select all data from a table into a single string output in sql?

Example: 
I have the following table (tableA) with the following data

```
Name        Age        Address
Jay         10         11 Happy St
David       12         13 Angel St
Tom         30         23 Betman St
```

How can I be able to select in sql to get the output as below:

Jay,10,11 Happy St\n\nDavid,12,13 Angel St\n\nTom,30,23 Betman St\n\n

Is this possible in sql script?

Comment: You can use GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: You should read and accept an answer instead of asking and then forget!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/588dd/6)):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name , ',', Age, ',', Address separator '\n\n') as List 
FROM tableA;
```

For Oracle ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/588dd/8)):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(Name || ','|| Age || ','|| Address,  '\n\n') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Name) as List
FROM tableA;
```

For SQL Server ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/588dd/10)):

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT Name + ',' + CAST(Age as varchar(10)) + ',' + Address + '\n\n' 
    FROM TableA
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '') as List
```

All return one string:

`Jay,10,11 Happy St\n\nDavid,12,13 Angel St\n\nTom,30,23 Betman St\n\n`

**Notice**: If the length of string return by the SELECT statement greater than 8000, there will be error or the string got cuts off at 8000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` , ',', `Age`, ',', `Address`, '\n\n')
FROM tableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DECLARE @result varchar(1000)

SET @result = ''

SELECT @result = @result + Name + ',' + Cast(Age as varchar(10)) +','+Address  +'\n\n' FROM TableA
select substring(@result, 0, len(@result) - 1)
```

output:Jay,10,11 Happy St\n\nDavid,12,13 Angel St\n\nTom,30,23 Betman St\n